# Flexbox not working with 100% width on image, 100% width needed for svg cut-off

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

So I have the following div:

```
.outer-div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

It contains an svg image which itself has the following class:

```
.logo-main { /* style for the svg image*/
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I want my svg image to appear at the left, so flex-start should apply.

However, my svg image is always centered within the parent div. I can get the image to appear at the very left (flex-start) by removing the `width:100%` from the svg image's CSS (.logo-main). However, I *then* have the problem that my svg is cut off on the right hand side.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the outcome you're trying to achieve? Without the HTML or a mock-up of your desired outcome it's a bit unclear

Comment: oh, so sorry, i edited the post and must have gotten rid of the most essential part (or I forgot it all along)! Will edit, thank you for that.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can see exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, you need to put a codepen or something here for the community to help you. It sounds like you need to change your 'Viewbox' sizing togh.